# Cascading Delete of Table with Entity Framework Core

Tags: database, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Platform: .NET Core 6 using EF Core.

The following is my schema

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ScenarioSetId { get; set; }
    public virtual ScenarioSet ScenarioSet { get; set; }
}

public class ScenarioSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Scenario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ScenarioSet ScenarioSet{ get; set; }
    public int ScenarioSetId { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedScenarios
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int ScenarioId { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially, a course gets assigned a `ScenarioSet`. Inside the course, you can pick a subset of the scenarios inside `ScenarioSet`, which get stored in `SelectedScenarios`.

I'm looking for cascading delete behavior where if I unassign the foreign key in course to `ScenarioSet`, all the `SelectedScenarios` for that `CourseId` that belong to the `ScenarioSet` get deleted.

Example:

- I create a scenario set with 5 scenarios A, B, C, D, E.
- I assign this scenario set to a course
- In the course I only pick scenarios A, B, C
- I remove the scenario set from the course scenario A, B, C for my course in selected scenarios should get removed.

I'm not able to find the correct Entity Framework behavior to achieve this. Can only find examples with relationships of 3 tables in the official docs.

Comment: Cascaded *delete* is only triggered by something actually being deleted. Since the action of removing a ScenarioSet from a Course doesn't delete anything, you'll have to do this manually.